# Touchpad Scrolling doesn't work on a Sony Vaio VGN-NW220F

Tags: touchpad, 12.04, vaio, sony

In Windows 7 (which was included on my laptop), I could use the right side of the touchpad to scroll vertically, and the bottom edge to scroll horizontally. In Ubuntu, this doesn't work and I see no setting to enable it. Is it even supported? I miss this feature. I just removed Windows and installed Ubuntu 12.04 beta.

Sony Vaio VGN-NW220F

Comment: Yep, I tried that first thing ofc. But I dont think that ubuntu found the touchpad, think its installed as a ps2 mouse. So how do I install drivers for the touchpad. sony vaio VGN-FW21E Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

Search for "Mouse and Touchpad" in the menu, there you will find touchpad settings there, and you can set horizontal as well as vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS  , search for "Pointing Devices " in ubuntu software centre , install it and scrolling works perfectly for ALPS touchpads !!